Running Puppetboard using Gunicorn shows set SECRET_KEY to a long, random string error
I have the Puppet Server v8, PuppetDB and PuppetBoard all hosted on the same Rocky 8 host.
I installed PuppetBoard using the following commands:
pip3 install puppetboard
pip3 install gunicorn

I am seeing the following error after attempting to run the app gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 puppetboard.app:app even though I have set a random string in the environment variable SECRET_KEY.
[2024-08-19 16:56:34 +0100] [6252] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6252
INFO:puppetboard.utils:PuppetDB version: 8.7.0
CRITICAL:puppetboard.utils:Please set SECRET_KEY to a long, random string, **the same for each application replica**, and do not share it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Can you share a secret key? And what echo $SECRET_KEY command shows?

@ViAchKoN The SECRET_KEY is generated using the recommended approach: python -c 'import secrets; print(secrets.token_hex())'

Yep, but without checking SECRET_KEY before the server starts there is no way to say why you get this error.

I managed to get this working. Define the SECRET_KEY in settings.py and set the location of the file in the PUPPETBOARD_SETTINGS environment variable e.g. export PUPPETBOARD_SETTINGS=/etc/puppetboard/settings.py before running gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 puppetboard.app:app
